# Cascading 3 filters

Tags: tableau-api

Suppose I have a table with companies and industries they belong to, such that each company has its own, only one industry.

For example (company1, electronics), (company2, clothes), (company3, electronics), ...

I want a filter that selects a company and then shows all companies that have the same industry.

For example, I select a company1 and I can see (either in a view or as another filter) all other companies in the industry electronics: company1, company3, ...

I tried to make 3 filters, where first (client_name) is a context filter, second (industry) is having values in context, and third (client_name duplicate) is having relevant values. But unfortunately in this scenario it selects only a company from the context filter.

How can filter all companies in the same industry if I select one initially?

Comment: can you post sample data to work upon

Comment: Please use sample workbooks. For example, one similar scenario can be found in Sales workbook, if you create a new worksheet, and go to Superstore Sales you will have city and country dimensions. In a similar manner, the question is how to select a city, and get the list of all the cities in the region it belongs to.